# Где правильнее хранить роуты в React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Их нужно хранить в отделном файле,например route.js или же в компоненте , например header? Или вообще в корневом индексе?

```html
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home}></Route> 
            <Route path="/design" component={Design}></Route>  
            <Route path="/adwords" component={Adwords}></Route>  
            <Route path="/hosting" component={Hosting}></Route>  
          </Switch>
        </Router>
```

Comment: в инициализируемом файле, например: `App.js` (по дефолту у CRA)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, значит я все правильно сделал: как раз там и находятся мои роуты.